# How to add real time data in Barchart using MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid Chart library to draw BarChart.
But not getting how to draw bars with real time data in on button click.
Can anyone please help me in this.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but this is really unclear. What on earth do you mean by "real time data"? Do you mean "adding to the dataset"?

Comment: You already asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41734589/5241933) and it was closed. Spend some time to make your question clear and we will try and help you

Answer (score 0):

After getting data store that in List(graphData). Then,

```
BarChart barChart;
/*List to store real time data*/
private List<Integer> graphData = new ArrayList<>();

/*List of String which contains X-axis values */
ArrayList<String> xAxisValuesList = new ArrayList<>();

// create BarEntry for group     
ArrayList<BarEntry> group = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < graphData.size(); i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, "generating for:" + graphData.get(i));
    group.add(new BarEntry(graphData.get(i), i));
} 

// creating dataset for group
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(group, "Label");

// combined all dataset into an arraylist
ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();  
dataSets.add(barDataSet); 

// initialize the Bardata with argument labels and dataSet
BarData barData = new BarData(xAxisValuesList, dataSets); 
barChart.setData(barData);
```

Comment: While it's nice to help out, you should try and acknowledge your sources. It seems you have based it on the tutorial here: https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-bar-chart-using-mpandroidchart-library-tutorial/

That's probably okay because it's not a straight copy/paste. If you include a link to the tutorial, it's probably better